# Multiple objects getting created when using Spring dependency injection using mixed configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I seem to encounter that problem, that when I'm configuring dependency injection for some classes using  annotations and others through the configuration in xml files.

I have a constructor injection, I need to inject the `SuperBean` object into the constructor of two classes and they get different instances of `SuperBean` because one is configured with annotation and the other one in xml file, so the `SuperBean` is defined like this:

```
@Component("SuperBean")
public class SuperBean extends InjectableBean {
```

The constructor of the class with the annotation configured constructor:

```
@Autowired
    public CustomBean(@Value("Any name") String name, @Qualifier("SuperBean") SuperBean superBean) {
        super();
        this.superBean = superBean;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

And the other class' constructor:

```
public CustomXmlBean(String name, SuperBean superBean) {
        super(name, superBean);
    }
```

And it's configuration in the xml file:

```
    <bean id="CustomXmlBean" class="org.arturas.summerfav.beans.CustomXmlBean">
    <constructor-arg name="name" type="String" value="The Big Custom XML Bean" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean name="SuperBean" class="org.arturas.summerfav.beans.SuperBean" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

So I seemed to notice that the xml configured class seems to have a different instance of the `SuperBean`, because the changes that are made on the `SuperBean` object are not reflected when accessing it through the xml configured class.

So how can I ensure there's only one instance of `SuperBean` here? (let's assume I want to keep both ways of configuring - through xml file and through annotations)

**Edit: adding more source:**

The `CustomBean` class:

```
@Component("CustomBean")
public class CustomBean extends InjectableBean {

    private String name;
    private SuperBean superBean;

    /**
     * @param name - Bean name
     */
    @Autowired
    public CustomBean(@Value("Any name") String name, @Qualifier("SuperBean") SuperBean superBean) {
        super();
        this.superBean = superBean;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

The `CustomXmlBean` class:

```
public class CustomXmlBean extends CustomBean {

public CustomXmlBean(String name, SuperBean superBean) {
    super(name, superBean);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving them the same name? I've never really tried that with Spring before but it might work (or create 2 and only keep 1).

Comment: @DanielWilliams But in those code samples I believe the name is already the same? I tried using id instead of name in the xml file, but the result is the same

Comment: Oh I misread what was going on. Can you try doing this in your XML? <constructor-arg ref="SuperBean" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the constructor returning a different class CustomBean - Can you please post the entire source ?

Edit: Adding answer from comments into main answer

Sorry, I got mislead by the initial post. Try this

```
<constructor-arg index="1" ref="SuperBean"/>
```

Comment: This more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Well it's 2 different (but very similar) classes, that's why they each have their own constructor, one has CustomBean, the other one has CustomXMLBean, but they take the same constructor arguments and they're supposed to get loaded with the same SuperBean.

Comment: Sorry, I got mislead by the initial post.
Try this 
<constructor-arg index="1" ref="SuperBean"/>

Comment: Thanks, this one worked perfectly. But could you explain some more about what is in here? the index="1" means we're refering to the second argument in the constructor, right? so if it was index="1" it would be index="0"? And ref="SuperBean" means that it refers to a bean defined somewhere in the file or with annotations as "SuperBean"? Is it the name or the id?

Comment: Yes you are right, you can wire in the dependencies using name/ positional indexes. You were providing a new instance of SuperBean in the constructor.

Spring "overwrites" bean definitions if the ids are same - they are overridden in  the order in which they  are encountered by the container. Say you have two bean definitions in the same/other xml/ any other config mechanism, the 2nd one will override the first bean definition.

Comment: @JVXR Please update your answer (which really is a question) with the actual answer, which seems to be given in the comments.